# GET Posts request return html doc instead of posts on server but not on localhost

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a mern social media app where user can log in and then are taking to their feed where they can create posts and they are displayed on the feed.  Everything works on the localhost but on the server I can log in and see the feed and can even create posts that are being saved to the database but they are not being shown on the feed on there server.

This is the server.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const AuthRoute = require('./routes/AuthRoute.js');
const connectDB = require('./config/db.js');
const colors = require('colors');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const PostRoute = require('./routes/PostRoute.js');
const UploadRoute = require('./routes/UploadRoute.js');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

connectDB();

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());

// Serve frontend
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/build')));

  app.get('*', (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html')
    )
  );
} else {
  app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Please set to production'));
}

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`.yellow.bold);
});

app.use('/api/auth', AuthRoute);
app.use('/api/posts', PostRoute);
app.use('/api/uploadImages', UploadRoute);
```

I've tried moving things around but it hasn't changed anything.
This is my PostRoutes:

```
const express = require('express');
const {
  createPost,
  getTimelinePosts,
  getAllPosts,
} = require('../controllers/PostController.js');
const { authUser } = require('../middleware/auth');

const router = express.Router();
console.log('inside am in the routes');
router.post('/createPost', createPost);
router.get('/:id/timeline', getTimelinePosts);
router.get('/getAllPosts', authUser, getAllPosts);
module.exports = router;
```

Below is where the are initially being called and on the localhost and if I comment out all the code except the useEffect it shows the array of posts in the console but in the server console it shows the html doc.

Here is the file:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getTimeLinePosts } from '../../../actions/postAction';
import Post from '../Post/Post.js';
import PulseLoader from 'react-spinners/FadeLoader';

const Posts = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.authReducer.authData);
  const { posts, loading, error } = useSelector((state) => state.postReducer);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    dispatch(getTimeLinePosts(user._id));
  }, [dispatch, user._id]);

  return (
    <div className="Posts">
      {loading ? (
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <PulseLoader
            color="#485639"
            height={15}
            width={5}
            loading={loading}
          />
        </div>
      ) : posts ? (
        posts.map((post, i) => (
          <Post key={i} post={post} index={i} user={user} />
        ))
      ) : (
        "You haven't shared anything yet."
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

Here is the postRequest

```
import axios from 'axios';
//import * as PostsApi from '../api/PostsRequests';

export const getTimeLinePosts = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  console.log(id);
  const API_URL = '/api/posts/';
  dispatch({ type: 'RETREIVING_START' });
  try {
    //const { data } = await PostsApi.getTimelinePosts(id);
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/posts/${id}/timeline`);
    console.log(data);
    dispatch({ type: 'RETREIVING_SUCCESS', data: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: 'RETREIVING_FAIL' });
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

And here is the postReducer

```
const postReducer = (
  state = { posts: null, loading: false, error: false, uploading: false },
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    // belongs to PostShare.jsx
    case 'ADDPOST_START':
      return { ...state, error: false, uploading: true };
    case 'ADDPOST_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: [action.data, ...state.posts],
        uploading: false,
        error: false,
      };
    case 'ADDPOST_FAIL':
      return { ...state, uploading: false, error: true };
    // belongs to Posts.jsx
    case 'RETREIVING_START':
      return { ...state, loading: true, error: false };
    case 'RETREIVING_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: action.data,
        loading: false,
        error: false,
      };
    case 'RETREIVING_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: true };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default postReducer;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Short answer*: **The lines serving static assets should be placed after all the other routes** in the server file.

*Long answer*: Please put the following lines

```
// Serve frontend
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/build')));

  app.get('*', (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html')
    )
  );
```

after the following lines:

```
app.use('/api/auth', AuthRoute);
app.use('/api/posts', PostRoute);
app.use('/api/uploadImages', UploadRoute);
```

**Express JS interprets routes based on the order they are written** in the server file, therefore the static assets should be served after all the other routes. This should solve the problem you are having.

Comment: No, first we should check if there's a match for physical files trough express.static miiddleware, then later we respond to http requests.

Comment: @JonePolvora kindly read my complete answer again.

Comment: I didn't work, but I put a check to see if the posts.js page was getting any posts "posts && console.log(posts)". It still just prints the html but it prints it three times, if that matters.

Comment: It actually did work.  Something happened and I had to rebuild the server and when I did your solution worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're conditionally adding a catch all handler `app.get("*")` to the express pipeline, which will make your api routes unreachable. The `express.static` middleware is already handling paths that are mapped to physical files, in case no file found, it just passes the request to the next middleware.

A possible fix could be a refactor in code, maybe just remove the check for production and the catch all handler.

Notice that the api routes should be set before calling `app.listen()`.

```js
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());

// Serve frontend

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/build')));

app.use('/api/auth', AuthRoute);
app.use('/api/posts', PostRoute);
app.use('/api/uploadImages', UploadRoute);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`.yellow.bold);
});
```

I don't know why you're enforcing for production mode in NODE_ENV, the app should work in either environments.

Comment: I didn't work.  I do think it made a difference , before in the devtools in redux the postReducer was always null on ther server, not it has a value but it's the html that is being posted.   I put a check to see if the posts.js page was getting any posts "posts && console.log(posts)". It still just prints the html but it prints it three times, if that matters.

Comment: you need to see the network tab if is there running ajax requests (fecth/xhr), and if console is emitting error messages.

Comment: The network tab shows that the request was made with a status of 200 and shows Request URL: http://173.255.205.85/api/posts/643f61f952518863942e7677/timeline/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 173.255.205.85:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: And what about the response content ? What is coming from Network response (look into network tab)

Comment: probably the content result is the index.html content, so as I said above, remote the app.get("*") route,. All get requests will return the same result

Comment: I did that.  I have what you posted but still get the index.html.

Comment: finally I've found the issue cause. The problem is all about paths of serrving static files, your directory structure, maybe youir webpack.config

Comment: But how can I identify the issue and fix it.   I haven't changed the file structore.  I created the frontend with create-react-app.

Comment: please edit your question tellng us how is structured your directories.